# Updating a gridview based on dundas chart callback

Tags: gridview, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-2.0, dundas

I have a dundas pie chart which when clicked issues a client callback which updates another chart associated with it. Basically its like a drill down thing. I also want to update my gridview based on the user's selection of the pie. But since the update of chart is being done using dundas client callback I'm unable to rebind my Gridview. Is there any way to do it? .

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to "solve" it would be using OnClick ajax callback and
yourChart.CallbackManager.UpdateClientControl(yourGrid) method.

But the grid might revert on postback. The reason is that Dundas Charts is a crappy piece of shit when it comes to non-standard scenarios and their support won't help you. Don't use it if you can.

Comment: I'll do this in server-side OnClick handler to emulate post-back:

MyChart.CallbackManager.ExecuteClientScript( _
            String.Format("__doPostBack('{0}', '')", _
                          MyUpdatePanel.ClientID))